# Porting from Linux to Windows, tm.sys

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux, wdk

I apologize if this question is vague, but I can't really get any more specific. I have a pretty large project that I'm porting to Windows. After finally getting it to compile with cl, and link with link.exe, I run it and get the following 'System Error':

> The program can't start because C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\tm.sys is missing
>   from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

It's a console application which requires no installation. Does `tm.sys` signify anything to you, perhaps a Linux dependency that I missed that Windows allowed during compile time but is now interpreting oddly? I'm looking for hints/guesses/anything to run with because I fully realize that my description (and lack of code example) is less than satisfying.

It is a C project with some mixed in C++ code (C++ accounts for maybe 1%), and is built using the WDK. The compilation yields 5 static .lib files and one .exe file.

Comment: http://www.threatexpert.com/files/tm.sys.html

Comment: `tm.sys` is refers to a Windows kernel module… as to what it is or why it blocks your program from starting, I don't know. Everything else you are doing seems fine.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's not a virus -- this is a clean installation on a target machine not connected to the internet.

Comment: @Conrad Meyer You're on the right track. Turns out I didn't need to use the DDK to build this because it's user-level, so that was itself causing some sort of dependency. ntoskrnl.lib was the offending library. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resided within `ntoskrnl.lib`. I removed that unnecessary library from my sources file and the executable ran fine. I'm not sure the significance of `tm.sys`, but lesson learned: KNOW YOUR DEPENDENCIES!